# How do I document projects within monorepo using Readthedocs / sphinx?

Tags: github, python-sphinx, monorepo, read-the-docs

I would like to use readthedocs.org platform to document a set of related software stored using monorepo principle. The repository structure is following:

```
/
+- ComponentA
|  |- docs
|  |- component-a-source
|
|- ComponentB
|  |- docs
|  |- component-a-source
|
|- ComponentC
|  |- docs
|  |- component-a-source
|
|- Makefile
```

I prepared the documentation for each subcomponent in its `docs` directory, and now I am in trouble: How to idiomatically set up readthedocs to host each of my components?

One solution I found is to import the repository three times and set path to `conf.py` manually in Advanced Setting section of web administration; however, I lose the possibility to use `.readthedocs.yaml` file configuration.

Another solution I have in mind is to create separate `docs` directory in the root and somehow merge the three documentations into this one. But it involves lots of duplication between components documentations and this "merged" documentation. I have only a little to zero experience with sphinx.

What is the idiomatic way to document monorepo in readthedocs.org?

Comment: I understand that you would like to set up a separate project for each component? There are some hacks to do it, I can give more detail provided that I properly understood your question.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Sphinx extension created by Read the Docs to manage this particular use case. Check out its docs at https://sphinx-multiproject.readthedocs.io/